# Using pandas and numpy to return only the rows with the differences

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have built a script that uses two Excel sheet (Sheet1, Sheet2) as dataframes (df1,df2) and returns an updated df1 in another sheet (Results) that outlines the differences between the two sheets.

I'm trying to find a way to ONLY return the rows that have differences in them.

**compare.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

filename = 'SAMPLE FILE.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(filename, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(filename, 'Sheet2')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet1',index=False,header=True)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet2',index=False,header=True)


rows, cols = np.where(np.not_equal(df1, df2))

df3 = pd.DataFrame()

for cell in zip(rows, cols):
    df1.iloc[cell[0], cell[1]] = ' {} -> {} '.format(df1.iloc[cell[0], cell[1]], df2.iloc[cell[0], cell[1]])
    df3 = df3.append(df1.iloc[cell[0]])[df1.columns]

df3.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Results', index=False, header=True)
writer.save()
```

**Result I'm getting vs what I'm looking for**

[image]

**EDIT:** I have edited my post to provide the right solution

Comment: Could you share a sample of the data?

Comment: First few rows in the result can be used a sample. Just make a change in any cell in Sheet2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `np.where(np.not_equal(df1, df2))` to get the right solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing the `.values`, use [df.equals](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) which returns a boolean and that can be your constraint as to whether to pull it into the final dataframe or not.